# Can we say scaling matrix is necessarily diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Can we say scaling matrix is necessarily diagonal?

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaling_%28geometry%29#Matrix_representation), yes

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjBEFOwHJoo#t=2m23), no

$S$ is scaling along orthogonal directions according to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTIwqnweaf8#t=51)

So, how to put them both together?

Comment: The Wikipedia article doesn't imply a necessity at all. It clearly points out that a symmetric matrix can perform unequal scaling along axes not equivalent to the standard coordinate axes.

Comment: @Nij, this comment is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Nij, the Wikipedia article you quoted states that:

> Non-uniform scaling is accomplished by multiplication with any symmetric matrix.

A symmetric matrix does not necessarily have to be diagonal. But there is a theorem that a symmetric matrix is **diagonalizable**.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix multiplication is a linear transformation 
$$A :\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m} \\ x \mapsto A x$$
that maps $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ into the column space of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, i.e
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{a}_1 \ | \ \mathbf{a}_2 \ | \cdots \ |\ \mathbf{a}_n \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{pmatrix}  = x_1 \mathbf{a}_1 + x_2 \mathbf{a}_2 + \cdots + x_n \mathbf{a}_n$$
where $\mathbf{a}_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$. So if $A$ is diagonal, the $\mathbf{a}_i$'s are an orthogonal basis, and the product correponds to an scaling along these orthogonal directions.